# Fixing floor border in the gap between hardwood floor panel and tiles

Tags: flooring

We have recently ripped out old carpets and replaced them with wooden floor panels. In some places there is a gap between the wooden floor panels and tiles ( in the chimney).... How do I fix floor borders in these gaps? Do I fill the gap with some product and then nail in the borders? Or do I use a adhesive product to just stick the border in place?

Comment: Do you have pictures?

Comment: It sounds like you're in need of some quarter round to hide the gap, but I'm not quite sure I'm visualizing your setup right. Are you using floating floors? As Joe says, pictures would help a ton.